# NestJS-Microservice-TCP Exception Error Handling

Tags: error-handling, microservices, nestjs

I'm testing NestJs, specially microservice section and I've found that every time the client sends a message to failing / disconnected microservice (TCP), this throws an error that it seems not catcheable on the client (at least, I've tried surrounding with try / catch the method) this.client.send(...).

`users.services.ts`

From the Gateway (publisher).

```js
async registerUser(user: RegisterUserDto) {
  const res = await new Promise<RegisterUserDto>((resolve, reject) => {
    this.usersServiceClient
      .send<RegisterUserDto>({ cmd: 'user_registered' }, user)
      .subscribe({
        next: (data) => resolve(data),
        error: (err) => reject(err),
        complete: () => resolve(null),
      });
  });
  return res;
}
```

`auth.controller.ts`

In the Auth Controller, the event is received using the @MessagePatter() function (listener).

```js
@MessagePattern({ cmd: "user_registered" })
async registerUser(@Body() user: CreateUserDto) {
  return await this.authService.create(user);
}
```

`auth.service.ts`

```js
public create = async (user: CreateUserDto) => {
  // hash the password
  const pass = await this.hashPassword(user.password);

  // create the user
  const newUser = await this.userService.create({ ...user, password: pass });

  const { password, ...result } = newUser["dataValues"];

  // generate token
  const token = await this.generateToken(result);

  // return the user and the token
  return { user: result, token };
};
```

This is the current Log of Error that I'm getting in the Gateway(publisher).

```
[Nest] 3011  - 04/10/2022, 12:29:48 PM     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...       
[Nest] 3011  - 04/10/2022, 12:29:48 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] ClientsModule dependencies initialized +21ms
[Nest] 3011  - 04/10/2022, 12:29:48 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 3011  - 04/10/2022, 12:29:48 PM     LOG [NestMicroservice] Nest microservice successfully started +22ms
[Nest] 3011  - 04/10/2022, 12:29:48 PM     LOG [RoutesResolver] AppController {/}: +26ms        
[Nest] 3011  - 04/10/2022, 12:29:48 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/, GET} route +2ms      
[Nest] 3011  - 04/10/2022, 12:29:48 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/, POST} route +1ms     
[Nest] 3011  - 04/10/2022, 12:29:48 PM     LOG [NestApplication] Nest application successfully started +2ms
Gateway API Microservice is listening on 3000
[Nest] 3011  - 04/10/2022, 12:30:15 PM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Internal server error
[Nest] 3011  - 04/10/2022, 12:30:15 PM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] undefined
```

This is the response if there was any error occured during the User register.

```json
{
    "statusCode": 500,
    "message": "Internal server error"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I searched for that error before after that the tcp microservice should return a Observable
on
auth.service.ts

```
createUser(body: CreateKnoteUserDTO): Observable<string> {
   const { name, email, password } = body;
   const message = this.Client.send<string, object>('createUser', {
     name,
     email,
     password,
   });

   return message;
 }
```

in auth.controller.ts

```
createUser(body: CreateKnoteUserDTO) {
 console.log(body);
 return this.appService.createUser(body);
}
```

that works for me.